# Is that possible to return arbitrary type on method annotated by @ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

what I want:

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public @ResponseBody Object getSomething(@RequestBody DataRequest req) {
    // return anything can be transformed into json
}
```

If I use concrete returning type on this method, it will work. for example:

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public @ResponseBody List<User> getSomething(@RequestBody DataRequest req) {
    return UserManager.getAllUsers();
}
```

Does Spring MVC support this? As I know Gson library can deserialize arbitrary Java object into json, while Spring MVC use jackson, I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Spring MVC support this?

Yes, Spring converts the returned object to a response body by using an [`HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html). With an approperiate Jackson dependency on the classpath, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` will convert the return type to the corresponding JSON representation, if possible.

> As I know Gson library can deserialize arbitrary Java object into
>   json, while Spring MVC use jackson

As of Spring 4.1.x, there is a `GsonHttpMessageConverter`. So you can use GSON for reading and writing from/to JSON. For more information on this topic, check the Spring documentation on [HTTP Message Converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-message-conversion).